# How to send Notifications to multiple users after an Event happened?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hey I'm new to android  and i made an application that enable the user to upload a file (Professor) so that Students can download it for educational purposes.

I came to point that i want when the professor upload something to the application, I need the application to send a notification to the users notifying them that a new File is ready. I'm using Firebase and I want to know if there is an easy way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Firebase Database along with FCM, you could make use of [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). Specifically, the Database Triggers.

Say, the professor uploads a file (maybe using Firebase Storage) you could have a trigger set to a node (e.g. `uploaded_files`) that will send push notifications to those specific users -- where I think making use of Topics sounds good here (students could *star* a Prof to subscribe for updates).

Simple and direct to the point.

Comment: I get The idea now Thank you , But that needs NodeJs Right ?

Comment: The language is similarly (if not identical) to NodeJS. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help