# how to send fcm notifications to a single device without using firebase console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am storing the registration tokens in my database. I want to send push notifications to the single device by taking registration tokens from database but without using firebase console. How to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send device to device messages using Firebase Cloud Messaging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435750/how-to-send-device-to-device-messages-using-firebase-cloud-messaging)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an app server or some Google Chrome extention like [PostMan](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en).

First of all, you need to understand the differences between [notification message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications) and a [data message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages), like how the app handles the incoming message if it is in the background state or on running on the foreground.

Secondly, create a payload and send a post request to FCM endpoint. It is well documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message).

Lastly, check the FCM response. Note that getting a success response doesn't mean that the message is already delivered to the app, but rather the FCM server accepted it for delivery.

If you would like to learn more about what parameters you can use and the definition of each response codes, check out the [Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP Protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#send-downstream) documentation.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firebase database to store your tokens and intend to send the FCM notification during an event, I suggest making use of [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44297478/4625829) for an idea on how you might use it.

If you just want to send a simple downstream message, you could [use Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309674/fcm-with-postman-the-request-was-missing-an-authentication-key-fcm-token/45310143#45310143) (also stated by @looptheloop88 in his answer) or [cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664911/firebase-cloud-messaging-send-click-action/44665817#44665817).